# recursive use of cursors not allowed - sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite3

```py
sql.execute("UPDATE users SET diamond =? WHERE id ==?", (diamond_, user_id))
db.commit()
```

Когда я выолняю программу есть вероятность того что вылзить эта ошибка - recursive use of cursors not allowed - sqlite3 python

Можно ли как то это исправить? Или обязательно надо переходить на MySQL?

Comment: Ошибка возникает при одновременных запросах к БД. у Вас почему так выходит? несколько приложений или это бот какой?

Comment: в любом случае, можно воспользоваться asyncio и aiosqlite, асинхронным решением для работы с sqlite. если уж совсем не хочется переезжать на другую БД